# Eclipse neon: I am not able use run configurations

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

Eclipse neon: I am not able use run configurations. I am getting a null pointer exception. Does anyone face the same issue. Any reasons you could think of.

Added the error log

1. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid  at
   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4514)    at
   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)    at
   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
       atorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.setWidthInPixels(TextLayout.java:3333)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.graphics.TextLayout.setWidth(TextLayout.java:3329)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Link.computeSizeInPixels(Link.java:213)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(GridData.java:491)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(GridLayout.java:221)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.computeSize(GridLayout.java:164)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.custom.StackLayout.computeSize(StackLayout.java:98)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(GridData.java:491)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(GridLayout.java:221)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.computeSize(GridLayout.java:164)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLayoutData.computeSize(CLayoutData.java:26)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.custom.ViewFormLayout.computeChildSize(ViewFormLayout.java:90)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.custom.ViewFormLayout.computeSize(ViewFormLayout.java:69)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashFormLayout.computeSize(SashFormLayout.java:47)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(GridData.java:491)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(GridLayout.java:221)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.computeSize(GridLayout.java:164)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSizeInPixels(Composite.java:238)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.computeSize(Control.java:663)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(GridData.java:491)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(GridLayout.java:221)
       at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(GridLayout.java:197)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1383)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Composite.java:1368)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:725)     at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:676)    at
   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.addContent(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:298)
       at
   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.createDialogArea(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:457)
       at
   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:158)
       at
   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.createContents(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:445)
       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)  at
   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)   at
   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.create(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:374)
       at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)    at
   org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1154)
       at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools$2.run(DebugUITools.java:619)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
       at
   org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:627)
       at
   org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:560)
       at
   org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.run(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:82)
       at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
       at
   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
       at
   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4415)     at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)  at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)  at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)  at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:802)     at
   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$8(ActionContributionItem.java:1258)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4415)     at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)  at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4233)
       at
   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3821)
       at
   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1119)
       at
   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
       at
   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1020)
       at
   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
       at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)  at
   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
       at
   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
       at
   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
       at
   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
       at
   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
       at
   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
       at
   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
       at
   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)    at
   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)   at
   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

Comment: Without a stack trace, I'd suggest downloading a fresh copy from http://download.eclipse.org/ and updating to the latest Oracle JDK.

Comment: What build of Neon, the final release is not quite yet. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.